# Deploying a package created in Python 3.6 (Anaconda) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda

I have created a code to pull data from sharepoint and it works like charm on my local environment (Spyder Python 3.6).
But when I try to deploy it on production environment (Python 2.7.12), it fails for a missing package cryptography.
When I try to add cryptography from github to library of Python 2.7, it fails missing the file _constant_time.
But when I try to copy library files from anaconda (python 3.6 ) to production (python 2.7), the _constant_time file is there but it now shows cannot import lib error.

Why is there difference in files on github and anaconda for cryptography library and how to fix the issue?
PS- I can't change the version of production from Python 2.7

```
import sys
from os.path import join as filejoin
from  os.path import dirname as file_dirname
from os.path import abspath as file_abspath



binPath=file_dirname(sys.argv[0])
CustomLibraryPath=filejoin(file_abspath(binPath+'/../..'),'CustomLibrary')
print(CustomLibraryPath)
sys.path.append(CustomLibraryPath) 


from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from shareplum import Site
import pandas as pd


username = """xxxxxxx"""
password = "xxxxxxxx"
site_url="xxxxxxx"


auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
site = Site(site_url, auth=auth)
sp_list = site.List('xxxxxxx')
data = sp_list.GetListItems("All Items")



df=pd.DataFrame(data)


print (df.head())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: Cryptography has several different builds between what your production server would recognize and what you tried to grab from Github (As an example, Anaconda has several 2.7.x build options of cryptography, 15 to be precise https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cryptography/files) which makes sense because you are trying to use two different Python languages and forcing them to interact but they don't understand each other.

Think of your problem like this: Imagine trying to have a conversation in English (or any language for that matter) with someone from the 1800s  - *technically* you two are speaking the same language but you wouldn't understand each other as over the course of two hundred years because the language has evolved in complexity and meaning. For reference, Python 2.7.0 was released in July 2010, Python 3.7 was released 2017.

There is a hard way and a easier way to resolve this problem.

The harder way is: Find the exact Python build of production server, download that 2.7.x version from Github or Anaconda. Then delete your current version of cryptography, install the compatible version of cryptography. Then make sure Anaconda recognizes the new branch, implement it your code and it should make it work on your production server. You will have to do some trial and error to get it right because other packages may have dependence issues with your older version of cryptography. Which given what you presented as your solution is what I believe you attempted.

However, to avoid your current frustration, there is an easier way: **build a virtual environment for Python 2.7.x on your machine that matches the production server.**

I would specifically use virtualenv, pip install your packages, then implement your code through it. That way your code and the production server use the same Python. I will add this small caveat: You may need to rewrite some of your code to make it work, because again, you built the code using the language of 2017, but you are conversing with the Python of 2010.

I'll get you started down the path with how to setup it up below, but I highly recommend reading the Python.org virtual environment page to educate yourself for future development (there are numerous articles and reference guides as well out there but start with the source): (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

To set up the virtual environment - pull up terminal and type the following below:

```
$ mkdir project_folder
$ cd project_folder
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

Once that runs you will need to activate it:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

From there you should be able to use pip to grab your modules (i would double check and make sure pip is setup for Python 2.7 -> I failed to do this with a build once and spent hours trying to figure out what I did wrong). 
Once all your packages are installed, it's customary to "freeze" the current environment packages (handy for other developers on project too or anyone who wants to utilize it later)

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Once that's done, you can copy the code and implement into it your virtual environment build of your program.

Comment: Thanks but I finally gave up and installed 3.7 on my server. I guess there is no easy way out of different versions of python.